# Add multiple values to Hbase table

Tags: hbase

I'm using Mapreduce to insert data to my Hbase table. Because I can not insert image so I just describe my Hbase table as following:

```
{
  "rowkey1": {
    File: {
      source: "path to file"
    }
    Features: {
      feature1: "value 1"
      feature1: "value 2"
    }
  }
  ......
}
```

In map function, I will get all values are: "path to file", "value 1", "value 2" to insert to "rowkey1".

But the problem here is that we just only can put 1 value for 1 family for 1 qualifier at the same time.

```
public void map(Text key, BytesWritable bytes, Context context)throws IOException {
Put put = new Put(key.getBytes());
put.add(family, qualifier, bytes.getBytes());
try {
context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(key.getBytes()), put);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So my question is does any way to insert those values to Hbase table at the same time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you do something like the following.

```
map(..) {
   ...
   for(value: valueList) {
    put = new Put(...)
    put.add...
    context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(key.getBytes()), put);
   }
}
```

You could do `context.write()` multiple times in a single `map` iteration.
Although if the number of iteration per `map` is very large, It might not be efficient. (Consider a different design or method in such a case)

Feel free to correct me if I understood your problem incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I'm newbie in Hbase so it is like silly question.